# how to change first part of a word via SED?

Tags: sed, terminal

I'm just wondering why it's not working :

Original

```
red wagon logon
Blue wagon logon
Black wagon logon
red wagon logon
red wagon logon
red walking 43 logon
red wagon logon 89
Pink wagon logon 110
red wagon logon
red wagon logon
green wagon logon
```

this command works well : `sed 's:wa\(gon\):poly\1:' wagon.txt`

Result

```
red polygon logon
Blue polygon logon
Black polygon logon
red polygon logon
red polygon logon
red walking 43 logon
red polygon logon 89
Pink polygon logon 110
red polygon logon
red polygon logon
green polygon logon
```

now I wanna for example `wapoly` but it's print `polywa` why ?

command : `sed 's:\(wa\)gon:poly\1:' wagon.txt`

```
red polywa logon
Blue polywa logon
Black polywa logon
red polywa logon
red polywa logon
red walking 43 logon
red polywa logon 89
Pink polywa logon 110
red polywa logon
red polywa logon
green polywa logon
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the capturing group from `gon` to `wa` and construct the replacement part as `\1` containing `wa` appending with `poly`.

```
sed 's:\(wa\)gon:\1poly:' file
red wapoly logon
Blue wapoly logon
Black wapoly logon
red wapoly logon
red wapoly logon
red walking 43 logon
red wapoly logon 89
Pink wapoly logon 110
red wapoly logon
red wapoly logon
green wapoly logon
```

---

`\1`, `\2` are captured groups form the `regex` in the substitution part, for example, in the line `s:\(wa\)gon:\1poly:` the part `wa` is captured in `\1` and can be later used in the replacement part as `\1poly` which outputs `wapoly`

To demonstrate the usage of `\2` using the same example consider, `s:\(wa\)g\(on\):\1poly\2:`, now the captured group 1, represented by `\1` has `wa` and captured group 2 `\2` has `on`, now constructed string `\1poly\2` will be `wapolyon`,

```
sed 's:\(wa\)g\(on\):\1poly\2:' file
red wapolyon logon
Blue wapolyon logon
Black wapolyon logon
red wapolyon logon
red wapolyon logon
red walking 43 logon
red wapolyon logon 89
Pink wapolyon logon 110
red wapolyon logon
red wapolyon logon
green wapolyon logon
```